# VSCode Tries to install to a nonexistent user

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

When trying to install VSCode, the installer tries to install to a directory called `C:\Users\gamer` even though it no longer exists, since I switched to `C:\Users\Marcus`. I made sure to change my PATH variables, so I don't understand why it's trying to install to a nonexistent directory. [These are my PATH variables,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaPnT.png) how do I fix this issue?